# Cast String to Array

Tags: go

I am trying to convert a string which is like

```
[{"a":"b"}, {"a":"d"}]
```

to a Array/slice.
Is there any way to cast string to a Array?

Solution:
My goal was to have a array of struct from provided json. But in my code i was doing something wrong, which result into this. Got the solution.

Comment: Would this be fair to summarize as "convert JSON to array"?

Comment: You can covert a string `s` to a slice with `[]byte(s)`, but you are probably asking how to decode json. There are hundreds of similar question and lots of documentation. What have you tried?

Comment: @user2864740 if you look closely, it is not actually a JSON. It's list of json.

Comment: @AshishMittal "I am trying to convert a string which is like" would indicate that the value shown is a single content of text. The alternative in context is ..?

Comment: @AshishMittal: if you look closely at what? What you have shown is perfectly valid json, and will unmarshal without error.

Comment: Got the solution. I need to use []structtype to get the desired result. thanks @JimB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your example is JSON, you can easily convert the input:

```golang
const input = `[{"a":"b"}, {"a":"d"}]`

type arrayValue struct {
    A string `json:"a"`
}

func main() {
    // parse JSON to []arrayValue
    var arr []arrayValue
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &arr); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // convert []arrayValue to []string
    var strArr = make ([]string, len(arr))
    for i, val := range arr {
        strArr[i] = val.A
    }
    fmt.Println(strArr) // [b d]
}
```

Try it: https://play.golang.org/p/KMsx1OaisGl